# Typescript Node.js simplest setup doesn't work -- error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've installed TS and the node typings globally:

```
PS C:\Projects\Test> npm list --global --depth=0
C:\Users\Jan\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- @types/node@7.0.5
+-- tslint@4.4.2
`-- typescript@2.2.1
```

Then I've created a file test.ts

```
import fs = require("fs");
let text = fs.readFileSync("myFile.txt");
console.log(text);
```

Runnning tsc results in

```
PS C:\Projects\Test> tsc .\test.ts
test.ts(1,21): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'fs'.
```

Do I miss something obvious?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't the import look like this `import * as fs from "fs";`?

Comment: Just tried it. Same error message.

Comment: You need to install type definition for the module: `npm install --save @types/node`

Comment: I did ... but globally `npm install --global @types/node`. Shouldn't this work too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should install `@types` locally to your project.

`npm install @types/node --save-dev`

TypeScript will not find globally installed types as definition files.

Comment: I installed the module but it's still doing it. Same issue as [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5812)...

Comment: Same here. I guarantee you @types/node is installed. Still not working

Comment: not working. I  can assure you that I have spent 6 hours already on this issue and tried any possible solution available